# Can I use an Enum with floating point values and comparators in Python 3.9 and still leverage the efficiency of numpy operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, enums

For a Python 3.9 project, we would like to use `Enums` because we have binning on a number of properties as per the example below. Unfortunately, these bins correspond to real numbers and will be used in large formulae, so `IntEnum` probably isn't much of an option.

For example:

```
from enum import Enum

class WaterVapor(Enum):
    VERY_DRY = 0.2
    DRY = 0.5
    MEDIAN = 0.8
    WET = 1.0
```

If I were to, say, implement a `ComparableEnum` that implements the necessary comparison operators and simply compares the `value`s of two `ComparableEnum`s, and I populated a numpy `array` of these, would I still get the performance benefits of numpy when doing operations on this array? My intuition tells me no, but I haven't found a definitive answer yet.

Any alternative design recommendations if my intuition is correct would also be very much appreciated. Using floating point numbers is essential to the computations that we will be doing, and so are the performance enhancements offered by numpy. Limiting them to specific values would be really nice to have, but not at the expense of the other two factors.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *how* you'd be using these float values with numpy? Are you just going to use them to populate some numpy array (which can use numpy's internal float types from then on), or do you expect to get your enum values back out of the numpy array after doing some processing? Have you tried inheriting from both `Enum` and `float`?

Comment: It's still early in the design process, but I'm fairly certain that retrieving the values back won't be necessary since these are just going to be used internally for calculations and will be immutable. We have to determine visibility and perform visibility calculations by filtering on and multiplying numbers of different binned `float` arrays. I hadn't thought about inheriting from `Enum` and `float`, but I just tried `class WaterVapor(float, Enum)` and it seems to have worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to inherit from `float`:

```py
from enum import Enum

class WaterVapor(float, Enum):
    VERY_DRY = 0.2
    DRY = 0.5
    MEDIAN = 0.8
    WET = 1.0

print(WaterVapor.VERY_DRY.value)
```

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely perfect! Thanks so much to you and Blckknght for teaching me something I didn't know you could do.